# Why is an argument of type double ** incompatible with a parameter of type const double **

Tags: c

I get a message about passing an incompatible pointer type from gcc when I pass a double ** to a function that expects a const double **. This is confusing to me since const double ** just puts more constraints on the use of the parameter passed in. How is this essentially different from passing a double * to a function that expects a const double *?

Added later: Passing double ** to a function that expects const double * const * is similarly problematic, any idea what can go wrong for this?

Comment: @nm that thread is tagged C++  (the answer is different in C, sadly, although some of the answers on that thread do addres it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass a pointer to a `const T` by value, the function cannot edit the caller's pointer, nor the `T`, so all is safe.

If you pass a pointer to a pointer to a `const T` by value, the function can't edit the `T`, but it *can* edit the second pointer.  And since the pointee types are different (const vs mutable), that can wreck havoc.

```
static const double PI = 3.14;
void function(const double** p)  {
  *p = &PI; //point at the const double PI
}
int main() {
    double* p;
    function(&p); //pass pointer to pointer to double
    *p = -1; //changing a static const global!  That's bad!
}
```

[Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) observes that if the parameter was `const double*const*` then C++ would allow it, thought C doesn't, probably due to simple oversight.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up. Why do I still get a similar message if the functions expects a const double * const *?

Comment: @acarchau: Honestly, I don't know.  I think that that should be allowed, but the C++ doesn't allow it officially.

Comment: @MooingDuck C++ allows it but C doesn't  (probably an oversight)